How do I make transparency work in EEVEE in 4.3 and 4.4
I cannot find settings-Blend Mode, opaque/alpha clip/ alpha hash/alpha blend in Blender 4.3 or 4.4 and its really frustrating.  What happened to it, where did it move to, or what do we have to now do to replicate this feature?  Why was it removed?  This has become a rather annoying frustration, and there is nothing I can find anywhere on it.  Thank you for any help you can provide.
